# What is the mathematical word to describe when two objects can be transformed to each other like Klein bottle and torus?

Tags: general-topology, terminology

In mathematics how does one say that two objects like the Klein bottle and a torus can be transformed into each other and are the same thing in some sense?

Comment: [Homeomorphic?](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homeomorphism)

Comment: @DreamConspiracy yes, thank you.

Comment: @katerine To be clear, a torus and the Klein bottle are NOT homeomorphic.

Answer (score 4):

There are a few notions depending on what type of equivalence you want to consider.

• A diffeomorphism of two manifolds $M$ and $N$ is a smooth bijection $f:M\to N$ with smooth inverse.

• Homeomorphism of two topological spaces $X$ and $Y$  is when there exists a map $f:X\to Y$ which is  a continuous bijection with continuous inverse.

• A homotopy equivalence of spaces is a pair of maps $f:X\to Y$ and $g:Y\to X$ with $g\circ f\simeq \operatorname{Id}_X$ and $f\circ g \simeq \operatorname{Id}_Y$.

Diffeomorphism $\implies$ Homeomorphism $\implies$ Homotopy Equivalence.

There are also other notions of equivalence like isometry, etc.

Answer (score 2):

Expanding my comment into an answer: The term is [homeomorphic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homeomorphism). In particular, we call two topological spaces homeomorphic if there exists $f:X\to Y$ such that $f$ is a continuous bijection and $f^{-1}$ is continuous.

Comment: Note that the torus and Klein bottle aren't actually homeomorphic. (Also, the usual notation for the inverse is "$f^{-1}$.")

Comment: @NoahSchweber brain fart, thank you